# Bug in VS2010 ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I created a JavaScript file to use in my ASP.NET MVC3 application and it was working ok, 
until I made a change in it. Now my app is using my previous JavaScript code, which doesn't exists!!!
I've closed VS and opened it again, I've deleted the file and recreated it, I've remove the 
tag and set it again, I've even turn my computer off and on again, I don't know what else to do. 
This is really weird, if I put this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
```

I can use my previous version of `myScript.js`, which doesn't exists, no only where it is 
looking for it, but in my hard drive!!!
Is this undesired caching of VS or is it the browser (Google Chrome 23.0.1271.97)? 
Is this a bug? How can I fix this, please, I'm going crazy!!!

Comment: unexplainable so far. what else can you share?

Comment: This is feature: browsers caches JS, CSS, etc. Clear your browsers chache! Or change your script include to something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js?r=12345"></script>`

Comment: Try Ctrl-R in your browser to make it update the cached script.

Comment: @nemesv thanks, I cleared my browser's cache and it worked ok, but, do I need to do this every time I make a change in one of my scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rather press ctrl + f5 whenever you change JavaScript.. It enforces browser to get fresh files from server

Answer (score 1):

Aman is correct:

```
CTRL + F5  --> is requesting a new copy as if there is no caching.
```

Side note, regular F5 is forcing a check so if a server in the path is agreeing with the checking of a cached version

Great tools to use to see what is happening

```
Firebug
Fiddler 2
```

Having said that, I have seen IE hold on to cache even with CTRL + F5,  and I used F12 Developer Tools and cleared items that way instead of closing the browser.  It can be frustrating to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly clear your browser's cache with ctrl+f5. It will update the information. And if you make some changes on the backend you will need to repeat this operation otherwise you'll meet the same problem...